# Maven project creation with local repository and local dependencies

Tags: maven, project

Problem :  pom.xml shows error as missing artifact.
           I have created the project with local repository and inside that i copied required jar files.
I tried to create the project dynamically like just putting required jar name and version in pom.xml but it was unable to find it like poi jar etc.

pom.xml
`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mavenproject.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>testproject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>testproject</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
<repositories>
      <repository>
         <id>localrepository</id>
         <url>C:/Users/anil/.m2/repository</url>
      </repository>
   </repositories>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
      </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
      </dependency>
       <dependency>
         <groupId>itext</groupId>
         <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
      </dependency>
       <dependency>
         <groupId>jasperreports</groupId>
         <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>poi</groupId>
         <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

`
Local Repository:Jar file present in local repository {shown few jar files}
[Jarfileinformation present in local repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8Qb2.png)
Effective POM:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mavenproject.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>testproject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>testproject</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>itext</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.1</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>itext</groupId>
      <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.7</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jasperreports</groupId>
      <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
      <version>6.2.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
      <version>3.10.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>localrepository</id>
      <url>C:/Users/anil/.m2/repository</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>D:\Anil Bhendarkar\Company Projects\Rolls-Royce\Workspace\testproject\src\main\java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>D:\Anil Bhendarkar\Company Projects\Rolls-Royce\Workspace\testproject\src\main\scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>D:\Anil Bhendarkar\Company Projects\Rolls-Royce\Workspace\testproject\src\test\java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>D:\Anil Bhendarkar\Company Projects\Rolls-Royce\Workspace\testproject\target\classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>D:\Anil Bhendarkar\Company Projects\Rolls-Royce\Workspace\testproject\target\test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>D:\Anil Bhendarkar\Company Projects\Rolls-Royce\Workspace\testproject\src\main\resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>D:\Anil Bhendarkar\Company Projects\Rolls-Royce\Workspace\testproject\src\test\resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <directory>D:\Anil Bhendarkar\Company Projects\Rolls-Royce\Workspace\testproject\target</directory>
    <finalName>testproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>D:\Anil Bhendarkar\Company Projects\Rolls-Royce\Workspace\testproject\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>D:\Anil Bhendarkar\Company Projects\Rolls-Royce\Workspace\testproject\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>D:\Anil Bhendarkar\Company Projects\Rolls-Royce\Workspace\testproject\target\site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>D:\Anil Bhendarkar\Company Projects\Rolls-Royce\Workspace\testproject\target\site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

I don't understand the problem.
My aim is to create maven project with this library as dependencies.

Thanks

Comment: Start using a repository manager and install the required jars into there and than simply use the dep. jars.

Answer (score 6):

For adding local jar as your dependencies, there are two way to achieve this.

1) Use **scope** `system`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version> <!-- Dummy Version -->
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>/pathToJar/poi.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

But using this way some ***maven building tools failed due to scope `system`***, like `maven-assembly-plugin` and `maven-shade-plugin`. To avoid this use following way.

2) By creating local repository,

Create directory `repo` in your project directory.
Run following maven command to install jar to local repository,

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl=file:///path/toyourproject/repo/ -Dfile=/pathToJar/poi.jar -DgroupId=poi -DartifactId=poi -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=1.0
```

Run `mvn deploy` command in project folder via cmd. If `mvn` is not installed in your machine then use following links for same.

[Install Maven in Windows](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/)

[Install Maven in Ubuntu/UNIX](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-ubuntu/)

And add local repository entry pom.xml.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>project.local</id>
        <name>project</name>
        <url>file:${project.basedir}/repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Finally add your dependency,

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>poi</groupId>
     <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
     <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This dependency will use jar from your local repo created in project folder.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I like to go for 2 option but mvn deploy: where should i run this command and why can't i copy jar directory to project repository.

Comment: @AnilBhendarkar Check update portion for your first question and with this command maven will create proper .pom file repository structure with you can easily leverage as maven repository.

Comment: It was useful to me for automating setting up dependencies with non-mavenized third-party jars. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By the way, for **Android projects** if you need to add it to the repo (for example in order to build your app at CI) you need replace

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}
```

by

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url rootProject.projectDir.path + "/common_libs"
        }
    }
}
```

at your top-level build.gradle file

Comment: Worked for me for another use-case "rootProject.projectDir.path" thanks

Answer (score 0):

In a modern IDE, there's no need to mess with the command-line. In intellij, I created one run configuration, then copied and modified it for each additional jar (I had over 20). Enter something like this in the `Run` text box:

> install:install-file -Dfile=poi.jar -DgroupId=poi
> -DartifactId=poi -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true -DcreateChecksum=true

Select the correct `Working directory` where your jar is, save, and run. To keep my `Run/Debug Configurations` menu uncluttered, I put them all in a folder (click the dropdown, then `Edit Configurations`, then this icon[image: folder]).